# Does Streambuilder fetches all the data from a firestore document or only fields that are needed?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

In my App I use a Streambuilder to show a list of plans that are stored in Firestore (every plan has its own document) on a screen:

```
final CollectionReference planCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid).collection('plans');

body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: planCol.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final planDocs = snapshot.data.docs;
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: planDocs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyListTile(
                      title: Text(planDocs[index]['name']),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        onPressed: () {
                          edit(planDocs[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) {
                              return ExerciseTable(
                                plan: UserPlan(
                                  name: planDocs[index]['name'],
                                  exerciseNames: planDocs[index]
                                  ['exerciseNames'],
                                  rows: planDocs[index]['rows'],
                                  planId: planDocs[index].id,
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }));
```

On this screen, I only want to show the name of each document and not all the other data which is stored in the document(because they are very big). Now I was asking myself how efficient Streambuilder works when each document is very big. Does it load the whole document or only the field of the document, that is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On this screen I only want to show the name of each document and not all the other data which is stored in the document(because they are very big).

All Cloud Firestore listeners fire on the document level. So there is no way you can get only the value of a single field in a document. That's the way Firestore works.

> Now I was asking myself how efficient Streambuilder works when each document is very big.

It's more about the time that it takes to download those documents.

> Does it load the whole document or only the field of the document, that is needed?

It loads the entire document.

If you need only some names, you should consider storing those names in a single document. In this case, you can read only one document and you have to pay only one read.

Comment: Thank you! When I store the names in an extra document, how can I get access to a single document with all the data after clicking on one plan? By now as you can see in the code, I pass the data from the snapshot through the constructor

Comment: You should create a reference that points to that document. Something like this `rootRef/data/namesDocument`. So basically you should do it the same way. Give it a try, should work. If you have hard times implementing that, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, with what you have tried using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo if you have 20K documents, will StreamBuilder try to read them all at once or will it auto paginate ?

Comment: @PhillipJacobs No, if you need pagination, you have to implement it yourself.